# Multiple let statements on the same line in F#

Tags: syntax, f#

```
module Digits
type Digit = Unison | Semitone | Tone | MinorThird | MajorThird | PerfectFourth | AugmentedFourth | PerfectFifth | MinorSixth | MajorSixth | MinorSeventh | MajorSeventh type 'd GeneralizedDigit = SmallDigit of 'd | Octave type 't Number = EmptyNumber | CountedNumber of 't * 't Number
let swapOctave: Digit GeneralizedDigit -> Digit GeneralizedDigit = fun x -> match x with SmallDigit Unison -> Octave | Octave -> SmallDigit Unison | g -> g
let limitLength: 'r Number -> Digit = fun a -> match a with EmptyNumber -> Unison | CountedNumber(_,EmptyNumber) -> Semitone | CountedNumber(_,CountedNumber(_,EmptyNumber)) -> Tone | CountedNumber(_,CountedNumber(_,CountedNumber(_,EmptyNumber))) -> MinorThird | _ -> MajorSeventh
```

In F# I can put multiple `type` definitions on the same line without semicolons without any problems, but when I remove the newline between the `let` statements I get the error `FS0010`. I know that in Haskell statements can be separated by a single semicolon but in F#  neither a single semicolon nor a double semicolon will work. How do I have multiple let statements on the same line?

Answer (score 6):

You can do this with the `let .. in` syntax like so:

```
let f () = let a = 1 in let b = 2 in a + b
f () // gives 3 as a result
```

But I would really recommend against doing multiple single-line definitions like this. It's hard for people to read.

Answer (score 3):

If you want multiple let bindings to bound values to variables, then you also can use the "tuple syntax".

```
let x,y,z = 1, "Hi", 3.0
```

Answer (score 2):

As explained by Phillip, the `let .. in ..` construct allows you to define a local variable as part of a one-line expression.

However, your example seems to be trying to define multiple top-level definitions in a module, which is something you cannot achieve with `let .. in ..`.

As far as I can tell, you can actually do this by separating the definitions with two semicolons, i.e. `;;`. If I save the following as `test.fs` and load it using `#load`, I get no errors:

```
module Digits
type Digit = Unison | Semitone | Tone | MinorThird | MajorThird | PerfectFourth | AugmentedFourth | PerfectFifth | MinorSixth | MajorSixth | MinorSeventh | MajorSeventh type 'd GeneralizedDigit = SmallDigit of 'd | Octave type 't Number = EmptyNumber | CountedNumber of 't * 't Number
let swapOctave: Digit GeneralizedDigit -> Digit GeneralizedDigit = fun x -> match x with SmallDigit Unison -> Octave | Octave -> SmallDigit Unison | g -> g;; let limitLength: 'r Number -> Digit = fun a -> match a with EmptyNumber -> Unison | CountedNumber(_,EmptyNumber) -> Semitone | CountedNumber(_,CountedNumber(_,EmptyNumber)) -> Tone | CountedNumber(_,CountedNumber(_,CountedNumber(_,EmptyNumber))) -> MinorThird | _ -> MajorSeventh
```

I tested this in F# 5.0. It may be the case that this has changed in F# 6 which [removed deprecated features like `#light "off"`](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/whats-new-in-fsharp-6/). The removal of `;;` is not discussed in the post, but it may have been a related change. If that is the case, you may report it as a regression - but it is likely support for `;;` should also be removed!

As mentioned by Phillip, I do not see any reason for actually trying to do this.